# Writing to USB-disk slow. Why?

Tags: usb, performance, lubuntu

I have just experienced the following:

- USB reading performed normally: 30-40 MBytes/s
- USB writing was *terribly* slow: 0.5-20 MBytes/s, jumping up and down and averaging around 4 MBytes/s

Reading was tested with `pv /dev/sdb >/dev/null`. Writing was tested with `pv /dev/zero > zero.file`. The disks were newly formatted and empty. The system did nothing else. So it is not because the free space was fragmented.

`iostats -dkx 1` showed the disk was 1-10% busy during writing (which fits with the 4 MBytes/s on a USB2 connection). `top` showed the CPU was idle.

I tested this with several different USB-disks (including a 80 GB Toshiba 2.5" with USB adapter and a Western Digital Elements 8TB), and got the same result. So it is not because the USB-disks were shingled or with similar slow-writing features (some USB sticks have decent read performance but abysmal write performance - this is not the case here).

The OS was Lubuntu 18.04 32-bit.

The behaviour is was the same on 4 Dell desktops (Dell All-in-one) and 2 Dell laptops. The machines had 64-bit CPUs.

On another system the same USB-disks worked as expected: The same tests gave USB2 read/write 30-40 MBytes/s and USB3 read/write 110-130 MBytes/s.

During my 26 year of GNU/Linux experience I have never seen this before.

What is the explanation for the slow writing?

Comment: With 26 yrs of Linux experience, you offer very little information. Where are the dmesg logs?

Comment: The problem that I am home now, and not on site. There was nothing worrying in the dmesg.